# Find original value based on its known fraction and its percentage distance

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions, percentages

Y is unknown.

P is known.

D is the distance between Y and P.

We don't know what D is, but do we know what fraction of Y it is.

Is this enough information to calculate Y?

---

Example:

```
Y = unknown
P = 20
D = Y-P
D/Y = 0.6
```

---

I've spent some time transforming these numbers around but to no avail. I tried searching various types of percentage inversion but I cannot find anything that would lead me to this answer, nor do I even know what this type of percentage/fraction operation is called.

---

Update 1:

Snap, it just dawned on me, is it:

```
P / ( 1-(D/Y) )
```

?

---

Update 2: See the accepted answer for a fully explained solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your finding is correct. But for future references, you can always just use algebra to solve similar equations. Your starting point is
$$
\frac{D}{y} = 0.6
$$
We know that $D=y-P$, so substituting that in, we get
$$
\frac{y-P}{y} = 0.6
$$
From this, it's possible to solve for $y$. Multiply both sides by $y$ to get
$$
y-P = 0.6y
$$
Now add $P-0.6y$ on both sides to get
$$
y - 0.6y = P
$$
Taking the common factor, we get
$$
(1-0.6)y = P
$$
And finally, dividing,
$$
y = \frac{P}{1-0.6}
$$
I hope that all these steps are clear to you.